# How can I help my 7-year-old deal with anxiety?

Tags: primary-schooler, emotional-well-being, anxiety

My son suffers from anxiety and is constantly worrying about all sorts of different things. It can be quite debilitating causing him to get worked up and upset easily and he often has trouble getting to sleep.

My wife and I have both experienced problems with anxiety and have found techniques like cognitive behavioral therapy ([CBT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_behavioral_therapy)) and mindfulness very helpful.

Can anyone recommend any resources that may be more accessible for children?

Comment: I wonder if you can't use some of CBT to help, and also try yoga, deep breathing, quiet times, talking it out. Not an expert in this. I hope someone has more insight than I do. Best of luck.  I can help with individual behavioural issues, but am only practiced with children with special needs.

Answer (score 1):

I've been Googling and there's a lot of info out there. I used "helping children with anxiety" in my search engine.

I liked this article:[Huff Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/renee-jain/9-things-every-parent-with-an-anxious-child-should-try_b_5651006.html)

I hope you find information you can use, but also think that the school or your child's pediatrician may have some good insight.

Comment: Not that this is a one line answer, but it is basically a link-only answer, which can be added to by exerpting helpful tidbits from the article. Thanks.